# Преобразование строки из кода unicode непосредственно в unicode

Tags: python, кодировка, python-3.x, unicode

Есть полученная извне строка вида

```
stroka='{"attributes":{"162":{"id":"162","code":"color_podguzniky","label":"\u0426\u0432\u0435\u0442","options":[{"id":"64","label":"\u0417\u0435\u043b\u0435\u043d\u044b\u0439","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["46"],"image":"http:\/\/ekopups.ua\/media\/amconf\/images\/64.jpg"},{"id":"65","label":"\u0416\u0435\u043b\u0442\u044b\u0439","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["47"],"image":"http:\/\/ekopups.ua\/media\/amconf\/images\/65.jpg"}],"use_image":1}},"template":"#{price}\u00a0\u0433\u0440\u043d","basePrice":"218","oldPrice":"218","productId":"196","chooseText":"\u0412\u044b\u0431\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u0432\u0430\u0440\u0438\u0430\u043d\u0442...","taxConfig":{"includeTax":false,"showIncludeTax":false,"showBothPrices":false,"defaultTax":0,"currentTax":0,"inclTaxTitle":"\u0441 \u043d\u0430\u043b\u043e\u0433\u0430\u043c\u0438"},"size":"18"}'
```

Хочу заменить все символы вида `\uXXXX` на читаемые символы (в моем случае - кирилица).

Вариант `print unicode(stroka, 'unicode-escape')` в Python 3 закономерно не выполняется.

Comment: Подумайте, чем `print(stroka)` от `print(ascii(stroka))` отличается. Если входные данные в json формате, то следует использовать `result = json.loads(stroka)` (возможно следует `r''` добавить: синтакс у json строк немного другой). Даже в Питоне 2, `unicode-escape` является индикатором проблем с входными данными и/или кодом (почти никогда не следует unicode-escape использовать -- убедитесь что вы твёрдо понимаете разницу между объектом (например, строкой, числом) и его текстовым представлением (`repr(obj)`/`ascii(obj)`) для отладки).

Comment: В общем то, я именно так и решил данную задачу в итоге: написал `res=json.loads(stroka)`. Но я ведь правильно понимаю что где то в недрах `json.loads()` есть набора из шести символов вида \uXXXX на один символ. Ведь моя проблема была не в неверном отображении юникод символов, а в том, что в исходной строке юникод символы были закодированы соответствующими последовательностями.

Comment: Чтобы не гадать, приведите в вопросе результат: `print(ascii(stroka))`. Попробуйте понять почему `len(json.loads('"\\\\"')) == 1`